# Removing Duplicate Code

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am working on a project and I just wanted to get some help on how to approach this problem and help clean up the code and remove a lot of duplication.

I have an FAQ database table with "**id, user_id, faq_question, faq_text, sort_id**".  Now every time a dynamic site is created, I have an insert query which creates the site and then also inserts into the FAQ table with the default questions and answers that I want to use.

```
    $insertFAQ = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'faq_question' => 'Default Question',
        'faq_text' => 'Default Answer',
        'sort_id' => '1'
    );


    $Db->insert('faq', $insertFAQ);
```

The sort_id is there because they have the ability to drag the questions in a different order and it updates the database and shows on the website in the new order.

Now the problem is that I want to have 10 default FAQ questions and answers that will be created for every website.  If we get hundreds of sites in the database, that will be a ton of records in the FAQ database table which is pretty much all duplicated.

I know there has to be an easier way to do it, the only thing that throws me off is the sort_id because they could all have the same questions and answers but sort them differently.  And then of course they have the ability to add custom questions.

**P.S.**  - How can I add multiple questions/answers in the above array that I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS for having multiple question in the array you posted in the question, you can just have a multi dimensional array:

```
$insertFAQ = array( 
    0 =>array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'faq_question' => 'Default Question',
    'faq_text' => 'Default Answer',
    'sort_id' => '1'
),

1 =>array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'faq_question' => 'Default Question',
    'faq_text' => 'Default Answer',
    'sort_id' => '1'
),
 2 => array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'faq_question' => 'Default Question',
    'faq_text' => 'Default Answer',
    'sort_id' => '1'
) );`
```

and so on and son on.

as for the sorting - 
You can create a separate table that will just hold the sorting order, site id and question id.

```
id, faq_id, site_id, sort_order
```

Id a new site is created you just create a new entry for it in this table, and than the questions don't have to repeat themselves, your only specifying what order goes to what site.

Comment: Perfect. So really there will still be 10 records for each site, just referencing the 10 default questions and telling what order it is in?

Comment: Yup, that the idea, and when some one creates a new site specific question, that question will be added to the faq table + a new entry in the sort table...

Comment: Using the table structure @YonoRan suggests also enables you to have a question shared across multiple sites. For example if your default 10 questions are the same, you could simply add entries with faq_id set to older questions.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have a `site_id` field in the table. For global faqs the `site_id` could be `null`.

Then to get the faqs for a site:

```
 SELECT * FROM faq WHERE site_id IS NULL OR site_id = $site_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question... To me it seems you simply need to split the question/answer from the user record, and have instead a reference to a question/answer entry in the user record:

```
// insert if it doesn't exist
$insertFAQ = array(
        'faq_id' => $faq_id,
        'faq_question' => 'Default Question',
        'faq_text' => 'Default Answer'
    );

// get faq id of newly inserted or existing faq entry
...

// insert user
$insertUser = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'faq_id' => $faq_id,
        'sort_id' => '1'
    );
```